# Retrieve a div without parents on click event

Tags: jquery

I'm writing an application and I need to return a class of an element that I have clicked on.

Problem is that once I click on an element, I also get all of it's parents classes.

Code I use to retrieve class names:

```
$('div').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

This is a sample of elements:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
        Bla bla bla
    </div>
</div>
```

Once I click on a `.child div`, it returns me both `.child` and `.parent` class names.

I suppose there should be an easy way to fix this, but after a couple of hours of research I couldn't find anything.

Comment: Just try `return false;` on click function, after `console.log` - it does the event stop on first function call. If you want apply the function only over div.child, just change the first line to `$('div.child')...`

Comment: With `JQuery` there is always an easy way to fix things. Thanks `JQuery`!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to prevent the event from bubbling to the parent elements, use `return false;`

```
$('div').click(function (e) {
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    return false; // or e.stopPropagation();

});
```

`return false` from *within a jQuery event handler* is effectively the same as calling both  `e.preventDefault` and `e.stopPropagation` on the passed [jQuery.Event object.](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) ........

Read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1357151/601179) excellent answer for more info.

With `<div>` there is now difference between `e.stopPropagation()` and `return false` because `<div>` doesn't have a default click event like `<a>` or <`button>` do.

Comment: Or you need to stopPropigation

Comment: @Splash-X in jQuery returning false does that for you.

Comment: @Splash-X. I added that option, though it doesn't matter because `div` hasn't any default event of `click`...

Comment: I knew it had to be something easy! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Alnitak yes, stopPropagation is the same as returning false, but it can be set anywhere in your method (like the top) without the need to "return".

Comment: @Splash-X. And it's better to set it anywhere because...? it's exactly the same thing mate!

Comment: @gdoron _technically_ there's an argument that calling `e.preventDefault()` and `e.stopPropagation()` at the top of your event handler means that any subsequent exception won't change the behaviour, whereas a `return false` might get skipped.  It's slightly tenuous IMHO, since in well designed code that exception shouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 2):

Don't bind to *all* `<div>` elements on the page. That's quite inefficient.

Instead...

- use event delegation using `.on()`, binding one handler to the `body`
- have the delegation selector test for `'div'`
- then get the `.className` from the `this` that was clicked

---

```
$('body').on('click', 'div', function(e) {
    console.log(this.className);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

So now you have one handler doing the work for all `<div>` elements.

If you're using an older version of jQuery, use `.delegate()` instead of `.on()`.

```
$('body').delegate('div', 'click', function(e) {
    console.log(this.className);
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

---

**EDIT:** Updated to use `this` instead of `e.target` as suggested by [@gdoron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/601179/gdoron).

Comment: If the selector of the delegate is 'div' won't it just be `this`? Anyway are you sure that attaching a dynamic delegate to 'body' is more efficient than bind an event to all the divs? It's hard to believe.

Comment: @gdoron: If there are many divs on the page that should get the same handler, then it will require less memory overhead to bind only one. There is more processing to do per click, but click events don't happen frequently like scroll or mousemove events. But you're right, I could just use `this`. For some reason I was thinking there would be issues with the nested elements, but it seems that there are not.

Comment: @gdoron: Philosophical difference. :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to prevent the click from "bubbling" up to its parent.

In native Javascript you would call `ev.stopPropagation()` but in jQuery handlers you can just `return false` in the event handler and jQuery then does the rest.

See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/J6Wn7/) for demo.

Answer (score 0):

You added click event to all DIV elements but you need only one.

```
$('div.child').click(function () {
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

Comment: He wants to add the parent to the list when the parent (and not the child) was clicked as well.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `return false`

```
$('div').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop propagation using `event.stopPropagation();`

```
$('div').click(function (e) {
    console.log($(this).attr("class"));
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you have included elements. And function executes twice. Once in .child and once in .parent
Try,

```
<div class="parent">BLA BLA</div>
<div class="child">bla bla bla</div>
```

And see the difference.