# Prevent changes after async form submission?

Tags: jquery, jqueryform

So I have a function called submitEdit():

```
function submitEdit() {
    //var ffield = document.getElementById("form_eline");
    //ffield.submit();
    jQuery('#edit_line').css('visibility', 'hidden');

    var fieldName = jQuery('#form_eline input[name=efield]').val();
    var pageId = jQuery('#form_eline input[name=eid]').val();
    var fieldText = jQuery('#ve'+fieldName+'_'+pageId);
    var editBtn = fieldText.prev();
    var loading = document.createElement("img");
    loading.src = 'http://www.lookall.tv/html/res/img/loading.gif';
    loading.id = "loading";
    loading.width = 16;
    loading.height = 16;

    jQuery('#form_eline').ajaxSubmit({
        beforeSubmit: function() {
            editBtn.hide();
            fieldText.prepend(loading);
        },
        error: function(data) {
            jQuery('#edit_line').css('visibility', 'visible');
        },
        success: function(response) {
            fieldText.text(jQuery('#form_eline :text').fieldValue()[0]);
            editBtn.show();
            jQuery('img#loading').remove();

            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Sadly this isn't my work and I'm building on an already existing website. So the problem is that the server is slow to respond. Therefor in those few seconds it takes the server to send a response someone could edit another field thus overwriting the current values. Is there some way to instantiate the variables so they don't overwrite?

Comment: Why don't you disable text fields while server is sending response?

Comment: The values of the variables won't be overwritten. Only the values of the fields will change. One your request is airborne, nothing the user can do will affect the request payload -- apart from closing the window.

Comment: Or even better: `$('#form_eline').find('input, select, textarea').attr('readonly', true)` put it in your `beforeSubmit`

Comment: @dfsq Or even better: `$("#form_eline :input").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

Comment: these look like answers to me…

Comment: @AtesGoral. Or even better: `$('#form_eline input, select, textarea').prop('disabled', true);` I think it's the best so far...

Comment: @gdoron `:input` is a relatively new pseudo-selector in jQuery and it refers to input, select and textarea.

Comment: @AtesGoral. Read the note on the top of the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/).

Comment: @gdoron The one about performance? Who cares about performance in this particular case?

Comment: @AtesGoral. _am not I am_ cares... [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9084244/601179) **lol**

Comment: @gdoron You're confusing just disabling a bunch of elements with attaching event handlers to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `variables` won't be affected if the user will change the values of the HTML elements.

If you want the user to know the changes he will do won't affect because the request ha been sent already. just disable the elements.

```
beforeSubmit: function() {
            editBtn.hide();
            fieldText.prepend(loading);
            $('#form_eline input, select, textarea').prop('disabled', true);
        },
complete: function (){
            editBtn.show();
            $('#form_eline input, select, textarea').prop('disabled', false);
        }
```